# concatination in do operator argument doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

concatenation in do doesn't work

Can any one explain why
this code work:

```
do 'begin perform 2;  end;';
```

better say doesn't generate errors
and that:

```
do 'begin perform '||'2'||';  end;';
```

generate

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
>   LINE 1: do 'begin perform '||'2'||';  end;';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `DO` has to be a string literal.

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html):

> **Parameters** (...) `code` (...) This must be specified as a string literal (...)

An expression concatenating strings isn't a literal.